# Oracle XE container (as child / sibling) startup error

Tags: oracle, containers, podman, oracle-xe

In our CI / CD pipeline, and the agents are run as Kubernetes pods using rootless podman. In our application / solution we want to execute few test cases and for this we would like to spin up lite weight oracle XE and execute few SQL statements against the database in CI stage. We tried spinning 21 slim fast container, but we are getting startup error, for which logs are attached.

The error is thrown at line, we can see that services are started but the database is not started. But when we run the podman using root user the database is starting up and test containers are working fine. Any pointers on this are highly appreciated.

```
CONTAINER: starting up...
CONTAINER: first database startup, initializing...
CONTAINER: uncompressing database data files, please wait... 
CONTAINER: done uncompressing database data files, duration: 9 seconds.
CONTAINER: starting up Oracle Database...
 
LSNRCTL for Linux: Version 21.0.0.0.0 - Production on 14-FEB-2024 15:59:33 
Copyright (c) 1991, 2021, Oracle.  All rights reserved. 
Starting /opt/oracle/product/21c/dbhomeXE/bin/tnslsnr: please wait... 
TNSLSNR for Linux: Version 21.0.0.0.0 - Production
System parameter file is /opt/oracle/homes/OraDBHome21cXE/network/admin/listener.ora
Log messages written to /opt/oracle/diag/tnslsnr/podmanpodnonroot/listener/alert/log.xml

Listening on: (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(KEY=EXTPROC_FOR_XE)))
Listening on: (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=0.0.0.0)(PORT=1521))) 
Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=IPC)(KEY=EXTPROC_FOR_XE)))

STATUS of the LISTENER
------------------------
Alias                     LISTENER
Version                   TNSLSNR for Linux: Version 21.0.0.0.0 - Production
Start Date                14-FEB-2024 15:59:33
Uptime                    0 days 0 hr. 0 min. 0 sec
Trace Level               off
Security                  ON: Local OS Authentication
SNMP                      OFF
Default Service           XE
Listener Parameter File   /opt/oracle/homes/OraDBHome21cXE/network/admin/listener.ora
Listener Log File         /opt/oracle/diag/tnslsnr/podmanpodnonroot/listener/alert/log.xml

Listening Endpoints Summary...
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(KEY=EXTPROC_FOR_XE)))
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=0.0.0.0)(PORT=1521)))
The listener supports no services
The command completed successfully

ERROR:

ORA-12547: TNS:lost contact 
SP2-0306: Invalid option.

Usage: CONN[ECT] [{logon|/|proxy} [AS {SYSDBA|SYSOPER|SYSASM|SYSBACKUP|SYSDG|SYSKM|SYSRAC}] [edition=value]]
where <logon> ::= <username>[/<password>][@<connect_identifier>]
      <proxy> ::= <proxyuser>[<username>][/<password>][@<connect_identifier>]
SP2-0306: Invalid option.

Usage: CONN[ECT] [{logon|/|proxy} [AS {SYSDBA|SYSOPER|SYSASM|SYSBACKUP|SYSDG|SYSKM|SYSRAC}] [edition=value]]
where <logon> ::= <username>[/<password>][@<connect_identifier>]
      <proxy> ::= <proxyuser>[<username>][/<password>][@<connect_identifier>]
SP2-0157: unable to CONNECT to ORACLE after 3 attempts, exiting SQL*Plus

 to join this conversation on GitHub. Already have an account? Sign in to comment
Assignees
No one assigned
```

When we examined the alertXE.xml, we found following errors -

```
Full restore complete of datafile 1 to datafile copy /opt/oracle/oradata/XE/system01.dbf.  Elapsed time: 0:00:38
  checkpoint is 2571211
  last deallocation scn is 2564922
  Undo Optimization current scn is 1155040
2023-11-11T23:16:06.431231+00:00
Full restore complete of datafile 3 to datafile copy /opt/oracle/oradata/XE/sysaux01.dbf.  Elapsed time: 0:00:18
  checkpoint is 2571211
  last deallocation scn is 2570181
2023-11-11T23:16:14.252790+00:00
Full restore complete of datafile 4 to datafile copy /opt/oracle/oradata/XE/undotbs01.dbf.  Elapsed time: 0:00:00
  checkpoint is 2571211
  last deallocation scn is 3
2023-11-11T23:16:15.273899+00:00
Full restore complete of datafile 7 to datafile copy /opt/oracle/oradata/XE/users01.dbf.  Elapsed time: 0:00:00
  checkpoint is 2571211
  last deallocation scn is 3
2023-11-11T23:16:16.196162+00:00
Errors in file /opt/oracle/diag/rdbms/xe/XE/trace/XE_ora_1383.trc:
ORA-19625: error identifying file /ade/b/4286850503/oracle/oradata/XE/system01.dbf
ORA-27037: unable to obtain file status
Linux-x86_64 Error: 2: No such file or directory
Additional information: 7
2023-11-11T23:16:16.203892+00:00
Switch of datafile 1 complete to datafile copy
  checkpoint is 2571211
2023-11-11T23:16:16.208313+00:00
Errors in file /opt/oracle/diag/rdbms/xe/XE/trace/XE_ora_1383.trc:
ORA-19625: error identifying file /ade/b/4286850503/oracle/oradata/XE/sysaux01.dbf
ORA-27037: unable to obtain file status
Linux-x86_64 Error: 2: No such file or directory
Additional information: 7
Switch of datafile 3 complete to datafile copy
  checkpoint is 2571211
2023-11-11T23:16:16.220196+00:00okkmkkcdrfd
Errors in file /opt/oracle/diag/rdbms/xe/XE/trace/XE_ora_1383.trc:
ORA-19625: error identifying file /ade/b/4286850503/oracle/oradata/XE/undotbs01.dbf
ORA-27037: unable to obtain file status
Linux-x86_64 Error: 2: No such file or directory
Additional information: 7
Switch of datafile 4 complete to datafile copy
  checkpoint is 2571211
2023-11-11T23:16:16.231710+00:00
Errors in file /opt/oracle/diag/rdbms/xe/XE/trace/XE_ora_1383.trc:
ORA-19625: error identifying file /ade/b/4286850503/oracle/oradata/XE/users01.dbf
ORA-27037: unable to obtain file status
Linux-x86_64 Error: 2: No such file or directory
Additional information: 7
Switch of datafile 7 complete to datafile copy
  checkpoint is 2571211
2023-11-11T23:16:16.355543+00:00
zeroing database id of data file (0): /opt/oracle/oradata/XE/system01.dbf
zeroing database id of data file (0): /opt/oracle/oradata/XE/sysaux01.dbf
zeroing database id of data file (0): /opt/oracle/oradata/XE/undotbs01.dbf
zeroing database id of data file (0): /opt/oracle/oradata/XE/users01.dbf
Shutting down ORACLE instance (immediate) (OS id: 1397)
Shutdown is initiated by sqlplus@9b9508ed8b72 (TNS V1-V3).
Stopping background process SMCO
Shutting down instance: further logons disabled
Stopping background process MMNL
Stopping background process MMON
License high water mark = 4
Dispatchers and shared servers shutdown
```